# What's the difference between 'adopt' and 'adopt-openj9' in jabba

Tags: java

I set up [jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba). When I run

```
jabba ls-remote
```

I see this list

```
1.13.0
1.13.0-2
1.6.65
adopt@1.14.0-1
adopt@1.14.0-0
adopt@1.13.0-2
adopt@1.13.0-1
adopt@1.13.0-0
adopt@1.12.0-2
adopt@1.12.0-1
adopt@1.12.0-0
adopt@1.11.0-7
adopt@1.11.0-6
adopt@1.11.0-5
adopt@1.11.0-4
adopt@1.11.0-3
adopt@1.11.0-2
adopt@1.11.0-1
adopt@1.11.0-0
adopt@1.10.0-2
adopt@1.9.0-0
adopt@1.8.0-252
adopt@1.8.0-242
adopt@1.8.0-232
adopt@1.8.0-222
adopt@1.8.0-212
adopt@1.8.0-202
adopt@1.8.0-192
adopt@1.8.0-181
adopt@1.8.0-172
adopt-openj9@1.14.0-1
adopt-openj9@1.14.0-0
adopt-openj9@1.13.0-2
adopt-openj9@1.13.0-1
adopt-openj9@1.13.0-0
adopt-openj9@1.12.0-2
adopt-openj9@1.12.0-1
adopt-openj9@1.12.0-0
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-7
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-6
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-5
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-4
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-3
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-2
adopt-openj9@1.11.0-1
adopt-openj9@1.8.0-252
adopt-openj9@1.8.0-242
adopt-openj9@1.8.0-232
adopt-openj9@1.8.0-222
adopt-openj9@1.8.0-212
adopt-openj9@1.8.0-202
...
```

What's the difference between `adopt@...` and  `adopt-openj9@`?

There are also three to the top without any letters, what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you follow your provided link and scroll down on that page you'll see:

```
# list available JDK's
jabba ls-remote
# you can use any valid semver range to narrow down the list
jabba ls-remote zulu@~1.8.60
jabba ls-remote "*@>=1.6.45 <1.9" --latest=minor

# install Oracle JDK
jabba install 1.8
# install Oracle Server JRE
jabba install sjre@1.8  
# install Adopt OpenJDK (Hotspot)
jabba install adopt@1.8-0
# install Adopt OpenJDK (Eclipse OpenJ9)
jabba install adopt-openj9@1.9-0
...
```

So the difference is whether you want to use the ***[Hotspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot)*** (Sun, Oracle) or the ***[OpenJ9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9)*** (IBM, Eclipse) Java Virtual Machine (JVM).